# EF Core / Net. Core - CRUD - explicit column listing is a must have?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I do have following Edit method - why the commented line doesn't work at all? Do I really need to provide explicitly all the columns I have in the class?

```
    [HttpPost("edit-item/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditItem(customClass userInput)
    {
        customClass item = await _dbContext.customClass.FindAsync(userInput.ID);

        if (item != null)
        {
            //doesn't work but no error giving - await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); ignoring the changes
            item = userInput; 

            //works - but is it mandatory? Lot of 'stupid' work in case of many columns
            item.TYPE = userInput.TYPE;
            item.CUST = userInput.CUST;
            item.PROD = userInput.PROD;

            try
            {
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
                "see your system administrator.");
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to assign any updated values to the object read from the database.  You can't assign the passed in object (`userInput`) to the entity from the database (`item`).  When you do that you are only changing the object reference and not the object itself.  The database context still contains a reference to the original database entity and doesn't see any changes.

Answer (score 1):

What Mark said, but if you find your objects quite tedious to type out then there are object mappers ([AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) and others) that can take the work out of updating different objects with the same field names without typing it all out.

Comment: Thank you. That's valuable information, I will research on that.

Answer (score 1):

For simple (i.e. non navigation) properties EF Core provides you several [PropertyValues.SetValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.propertyvalues.setvalues?view=efcore-3.1) helper method overloads (from value dictionary, from object of the same or other type). [PropertyValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.propertyvalues?view=efcore-3.1) object for the target it is obtained from the change tracker entry [CurrentValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.currentvalues?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_EntityEntry_CurrentValues) property . e.g.

```
_dbContext.Entry(item).CurrentValues.SetValues(userInput);
```

Unfortunately there is no such helper methods for navigation properties - they must be updated manually.

Comment: That's interesting but need to do some 'home work' on that and test it.

Comment: As you wish. It is [documenteted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#saving-single-entities) and works. Accepting  "Yes" answer to s question which actual answer is "No"  makes no sense to me.